# List of slugs from custom post taxonomy for loop (Wordpress + ACF Pro)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I am using `acf pro` and `wordpress` in the latest version.
I have a flexible content field in which I want to display certain events.
The events that are shown should be selected by a taxonomy field where several entries (cities) of a custom post taxonomy (locations) can be selected by checkbox. (multiselect)
The return is an Taxonomy object.
I need a list of the slugs from the selected fields.
The list should be e.g. like: ‘munich’, ‘london’,

The relevant Code is

```php
<?php 
$locations = get_sub_field('select_locations');
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'events', 
  'posts_per_page' => 99,   
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'locations',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array(
      /* HERE SHOULD BE THE LIST */
      )
    )
   ) 
  )); 
?>
```

I tried several things but I can’t get it working.
I would be very happy if someone could help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answer. I found a solution with the help of a developer.

Just for anyone who’s interested:

```
<?php 
$locations  = get_sub_field('select_locations');
$locationsSelected  = array();

foreach( $orte as $ort ):
    $locationsSelected[] = $ort->slug;
endforeach; 


$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'kurse', 'posts_per_page' => 99, 'meta_key' => 'datum', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC',

        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $locationsSelected
                    )
        ) 
  ) );  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$category_slug_arr = array('example-slug-1', 'example-slug-2', 'example-slug-3');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'events',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locations',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category_slug_arr,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<pre>'; print_r($loop->posts); echo "</pre>";
```